# HTML:Iframe to be transparent and form elements inside the iframe to be editable in Chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, iframe, transparency

I have a small priece of code trying with HTML4.0

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">
<html>
<body>
<iframe marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" scrolling="yes" noresize frameborder="1" 
name="HEADER" src="1.html" style="position:absolute; top:0; left:0; width:100%; height:100%;
z-index:3 ;" ALLOWTRANSPARENCY="true">
</iframe>
<iframe id="ifrm_contract" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" scrolling="yes" frameborder="1"
name="CONTRACT" src="2.html" style="position:absolute;top:211;left:0;width:100%;height:30%;
z-index:2;"  ALLOWTRANSPARENCY="true">
</iframe>
<iframe marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" scrolling="yes" frameborder="1" noresize
name="CONTENT" src="3.html" style="position:absolute;top:356;left:0;width:100%; height:50%;
z-index:1;" ALLOWTRANSPARENCY="true">
</iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

1.html and 3.html are simple html files with static contents.
But 2.html is having a button at center of html file.
Below are my observations.
A>In IE 8,the code is working fine.The button in 2.html is editable(means,user can click it).Again in IE 8 ,the '**allowtransparency**' attribute is working properly .
B>In Chrome/Safari ,the '**allowtransparency** attribute is not working.But by default in chrome 2.html and 3.html is coming transparent despite their **z-index property** .
'**But my problem is the button in 2.html is not editable or user is not able to click it.It is coming disabled.**'

**Note**:As per my requirement ,I have to keep the height of the 1.html as 100% using **height=100%**.

Please suggest any CSS solutionto rectify this problem.
Adding the code snippet of 2.html also
    `<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">
    <html>
    <body STYLE="background:transparent">
    <!--Here Some static text content-->
    <center><input type="button" value="click" /><center/><br/>
    <!--Here Some static text content-->
    </body>
    </html>`

Answer (score 0):

Could use css for the iframe, something like...

`iframe {
    opacity: 0.4;
    filter: alpha(opacity=40); /* For IE8 and earlier */
}`

The opacity can take a value from 0.0 - 1.0

Comment: my problem here is **I am not able to click the button in Chrome** which is present in 2.html(i.e. 2nd iframe),where as in IE code is working properly and button is also clickable.

Comment: So the code property for 2.html need to be shared for this to be figured out, as the code you have presented don't have any buttons, only the iframe its self. You need to share the code from 2.html for us to look at and try and help.

Comment: Added the 2.html code in the question.It is just a simple code with once button.My goal is to enable it and do some simple event handling by clicking the button.

Answer (score 0):

So i don't seem to be able to recreate your problem, everything is working for me, i even changed the button to a Jquery one, and all seems fine, so im not sure really, hopefully someone else can help, or you are welcome to email me the files and ill take a look, but in terms of recreating using the code you have given, it seems to be working.

Pretty much Used exactly the code you provided, even tried changing the button type, and all worked fine.